How to make an effective appeal against deletion because it may be AI-generated
I wrote answers without AI, but moderators deleted them. I tried to flag it to take objection, but it was all overruled.
How to write an effective appeal? What things do I need to provide to prove I wrote the answers myself?
Edit 1: Screenshot of deleted answer:

Edit 2: Screenshot of my overruled flag:


Depending on the moderator - the bar for being deleted as AI is pretty high. That said, if your answers are about this standard, no offence but really clean grammar is something AI does well, and your answers shouldn't have been deleted for AI for that. What makes you think specifically that it was deleted for AI?

Clearly you used a tool, perhaps you should specify what tools you used to produce your answer when you make your appeal.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I never use any tool(eg. ChatGPT or other LLM)

It's clear you did just from this post. If someone looks at the grammar in the unedited version of this question and compares it to the grammar in that now deleted question, it's obvious.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk i cannot understand, i cannot use English well

"i cannot use English well" - That's the point. Your English on this question and in the comments here is not very good, but the English in the deleted answer you showed us is impeccable. How do you explain this?

Did you use a tool to improve your grammar? If you did, which one? Some grammar tools are considered acceptable, but others are gen AI, which is unequivocally banned on certain sites (include Stack Overflow).

So, i am using translator(eg. Google Translate) to translate complex texts @F1Krazy

@Anerdw I was used translator in this answer, but translator is not be banned on stack overflow

Google Translate is a tool. When you make your appeal, explain that you used Google Translate and not any GenAI tools.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks, i will update new results on this question

You should edit all this new information into the question.

To be clear: was that in fact the reason your answers got deleted - because they seemed to be AI-generated - or is that an assumption on your side?

@Joachim You mean that you want to see the moderator message accompanying the deletion?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution That would help, yes.

I don't think a private moderator message should be made public. However, the OP should clarify whether the deletion was due to the content being AI-generated or if that's just an assumption.

@Velvet A user is free to make that message public if they want to, it's the mod team that is restricted from sharing the details except under certain circumstances.

@ColleenV Thanks for clarifying. I have to admit, I'm impressed about this policy.

What "details or Clarity" does this need? How does this relate to only 1 network site? If you VTC something, unless its obvious, try to explain what's wrong with the question.

@Starship I'd say I'd like to see an edit that includes 1) Confirmation that the answer was deleted for being AI-generated. Even if it's just "I received a moderator message that explained why it was deleted, which was that it was generated by AI", it doesn't have to include a screenshot of the moderator message. and 2) What the flag they raised looked like and the reason for the decline that the moderator gave (if the flag was declined).

The way to appeal any moderator action is with the Contact Us form.

@Starship I edited it

@Machavity And what should one include in the appeal? A simple "This is wrong." is probably not sufficient or is it?

@Starship this lack focus and too broad. "How to write an effective appeal?" is like asking "How to write code?" - it needs more focus, so while I didn't take part in closing it, I won't vote to reopen as well.

@ShadowWizard There are plenty of questions like this (ex. What can I do to lift or reduce a suspension?) that are open.

@ShadowWizard Lack of focus typically means multiple questions but this is only one. I also don't think unclear because it's more like "write me code for this specific case", which is what most questions come down to.

If you ever get a result to your appeal, you can let us know, if you want.

As with appealing any other moderator action, you have three primary options, although the considerations are slightly different than most cases when dealing with allegations of AI-generated content.
Option 1: raise a custom moderator flag
I'm aware you've already done this, but it bears mentioning anyway. Raising a custom moderator flag stating that you think this case was handled incorrectly is usually the best first option for appealing a moderator decision. You'll be best served by including whatever extra information you can - such as what non-gen-AI tool you used, such as Google Translate.
Mods are recommended not to handle flags where they have a conflict of interest, so this should be a good way to get at least one more pair of eyes on the situation. I can't guarantee that every single mod abides by that recommendation, though.
Option 2: take it to the local Meta
You have the option of raising concerns about moderator actions on the local Meta of the site where the incident took place. Note, however, that such a post should be kept as neutral and objective as possible; don't even name the moderator in question, just bring the facts. Once again, bringing all of the relevant information for your defense will be helpful.
Option 3: contact staff
As with any other appeal, you can also reach out to staff via the "Contact Us" page or their support email (which I don't recall offhand, unfortunately). Yet again, including all of the relevant information - including what you've already tried - will improve your chances of a positive response.
A staff member will review your appeal. In the case of a disputed removal as AI-generated content, staff will compare the post to the list of documented heuristics and determine if removal was justified based on those heuristics. They should also reach out to the mod in question to understand under what grounds it was removed. If staff determines that it doesn't meet the approved heuristics, the post will be undeleted.

Just to be clear: Raising a mod-flag with the text "Objection: this post is not ai-generated" is not the extra information that will overturn the initial decision, no matter which mod will handle that flag, right?

It should be enough to trigger a re-check of the post, @rene, but probably won't do much to sway anyone's first impressions.

"including all of the relevant information" This may not be clear enough. Is it possible to specify these relevant information more?

"If staff determines that it doesn't meet the approved heuristics ..." I wonder how often that actually happens. It might not be relevant for specific cases but maybe for "a year in moderation" some statistics about how often staff determines that per year, just to get an idea.

That will be a challenging task because of the inherent difficulty of the underlying problem and one should seriously consider if an appeal is worth the effort and maybe instead simply move on.
On the outline it looks simple, just convince the moderator that handles the appeal, that you did write the content yourself (and only used allowed tools like grammar/spelling checks). It really comes down to this.
On the other hand, another or the same moderator already was convinced of the opposite. Without new information, how could you hope for a different outcome?
I can't think of much good information that could be delivered that really proves you wrote the content yourself if you did that. A video of you producing the comment perhaps, but that sounds like overkill and maybe still not convincing enough. I'd say it's an unsolved problem for the moment.
Just think about it, if there was such a foolproof method, we wouldn't need moderators inspecting and deciding (guessing) what are AI generated posts. We could simply require people to submit proof of origin together with their content.
What you maybe could do is describe exactly what you did to create that piece of content (which grammar/language tools you used and in which order), but I'm not sure that this will change much. It would depend on people believing you and why should they? Even high reputation users sometimes submit AI generated answers, nobody can be trusted.
All in all I don't think there is an effective way to appeal in these cases. In case you really wrote that content yourself, I'm sorry that you are a collateral victim of the fight against AI contributions and for the inconvenience you experienced. In case you actually did use AI, everything was done alright.

Usually in such cases, mods can take a look in others posts of the same user, however in this specific case OP has only one other answer, still not enough for mods to detect pattern for good or for bad.

@ShadowWizard following that logic, the mod should not deleted the answer without greater proof. Deleting content because of a suspicion, or because someone raised a flag is insufficient. I have raised flags specifically on ELL, querying the authenticity of answers that are still waiting to be handled. So, some mods have a very strict criteria about which answers should be deleted and some less so.

On the other hand, another moderator already was convinced of the opposite. It might have been the same moderator…? It says a moderator reviewed your flag…  It doesn't say who. What is the norm for handling flags about contributions deleted by a moderator? Must the flag be handled by a different mod?  I don't know the answer to that.

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні we don't even know for sure the reason was related to answer being identified as GenAI. But even if that's the case, with the scale of Stack Overflow, mods there might indeed have a more strict policy and delete even when it's only suspected as GenAI, without any actual proof. And as for mods reviewing flags raised to appeal their own actions, that's just something they don't do.

So if we boil this issue down, the OP's contribution was deleted because its English, which the OP admitted was run through a grammar-check software,  was too good. That is a very weak reason based on a single contribution.

@ShadowWizard "not enough for mods to detect pattern for good or for bad." Even if there are lots of other posts to detect patterns it's not enough, sometimes even high rep users switch to use AI. It wouldn't be foolproof either. And what good would it be to refer to your history. The mods already have easy access to it. It wouldn't be new information.

@Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні " It might have been the same moderator…?" Good practice (four eyes are better than two times the same two) would mean that moderators do not process appeals to their own decisions if possible. But I don't know. Will edit to that regard.

Some of folks that actually answered you question (e.g., described what you to write the answer with specifics to allowed tools you used) are very good. I'll add get very specific and include not only tools but EVERY SINGLE THING you did with as much evidence as possible .
Then make smart assumptions why you were flagged or now that you have the information use the stereotypical assumptions made about your English skill here compared to the flagged answer.
Explain the assumptions (e.g., My English in my answer seems AI based because I'm a ESL using Google Translate). Show your original non-English answer and how it was Google Translated.
Now take all that information and summarize it using a concise easy to understand method (IRAC .... Issue Rule Application Conclusion). Make sure that Google Translates while holding your summary.
Use your concise summary as a first VERY SHORT AND CONCISE 4-6 sentence paragraph, and then outline and type out your evidence in following paragraphs. Try to stay less wordy and more readable than ...say... my wordy answer...
Good Luck!
